# Show data assigned to variable from a CSV

Tags: php, csv

I'm loading a CSV file and looping over each line. I want to assign variables to each column (shown in the list line), then in the first instance, show each lines `$project` data. So essentially that will give me each project code per line.

I'll be using the other variables but just want this one working for now.

There should be 1000 projects but it's only showing one, where am I going wrong?

```
<?php
 $row = 1;
 if (($handle = fopen("users.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
     while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, ",")) !== FALSE) {
         $num = count($data);

                 $row++;

                     list($project, $rod, $rom, $asm, $contract, $site, $town, $postcode, $country) = $data;
                     echo $contract;

     }
     fclose($handle);
 }
?>
```

Comment: You don't need the `for` loop, just remove this part.

Comment: @NigelRen That just gives me one row. I want to show all rows with just the project variable showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the while, just use

```
$project = $data[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call `fgetcsv` in your `while` statement, this reads the next line from the csv file.  So you can either use...

```
<?php
 if (($handle = fopen("users.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
     while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
         list($project, $rod, $rom, $asm, $contract, $site, $town, $postcode, $country) = $data;
         echo $project.PHP_EOL;
     }
     fclose($handle);
 }
?>
```

Or to get a list of the projects...

```
<?php
 if (($handle = fopen("users.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
     $projects = [];
     while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
         list($project, $rod, $rom, $asm, $contract, $site, $town, $postcode, $country) = $data;
         $projects[] = $project;
     }
     fclose($handle);
     print_r($projects);
 }
?>
```